# How can I connect to IBM MQ via the AMQP API in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq, amqp

I am using "AMQPNetLite.Core" to connect to the IBM MQ server.

However, when I try to new the connection there is an OperationCanceledException thrown.

```
Address address = new Address($"amqp://{hostName}:{port}");
// System.OperationCanceledException: 'The transport 'TcpTransport' is closed.'
Connection connection = new Connection(address, SaslProfile.Anonymous, null, null);
Session session = new Session(connection);
```

The log in IBM MQ server shows:

```
The data received from host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' on channel '????' is not valid. [CommentInsert1(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx), CommentInsert2(TCP/IP), CommentInsert3(????)]
The TCP/IP responder program encountered an error. [CommentInsert1(TCP/IP), CommentInsert3(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)]
```

The channel is "????" in the log, does it mean I need to specify a channel before I instantiate a connection? But where can I do so? There seems no place at the Address and Connection classes to specify the channel name.

The server should be working, because I can send and receive message by the "IBMMQDotnetClient"

```
MQEnvironment.Hostname = hostName;
MQEnvironment.Channel = channel;
MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName);
int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;
MQQueue system_default_local_queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, openOptions);
// Send and Receive message via the queue
```

Comment: Do you have the AMQP service started on your queue manager and do you have a AMQP channel defined with the port you are specifying? Note the port will not be the same as a normal MQ listener port that you would point a IBMMQDotnetClient at.

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks for your reply. Indeed, I am not sure. I am following the instruction here (https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-connect-app-queue-manager-containers/) to start my testing IBM MQ docker container. I guess it is the default setting and most likely did not turn on the AMQP service as you mentioned. Do you have more details how can I check it or turn it on at the docker instance?

Comment: AMQP service is not enabled in IBM MQ docker image. See here for a response - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/issues/413. You will have to build your MQ container image if you want AMQP support. Otherwise install the trial version  https://developer.ibm.com/articles/mq-downloads/

Comment: Step 1 in this tutorial https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-running-ibm-mq-apps-on-quarkus-and-graalvm-using-qpid-amqp-jms-classes/#step-1-set-up-the-amqp-channel-in-ibm-mq shows how to set up AMQP in a MQ Container.

Comment: Hi @chughts Thanks for very much. Very detailed step-by-step guideline. Would you mind posting your comment as answer so that I can accept it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, it looks like you haven't set up the AMQP service.

Step 1 in this tutorial - https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-running-ibm-mq-apps-on-quarkus-and-graalvm-using-qpid-amqp-jms-classes/#step-1-set-up-the-amqp-channel-in-ibm-mq

shows how to set up the AMQP listener. We have more AMQP tutorials in the pipeline, and that step might soon end up in its own article, but the tutorials will continue to point at it.

**Note: ** The tutorial asks you to clone

```
git clone -b 9.2.3 ...
```

The current latest is 9.2.5 ie.

```
git clone -b 9.2.5 ...
```

The key substeps are:

> Enable AMQP in the MQ container by editing the install-mq.sh file, and
> changing the following AMQP line to:
>
> Export genmqpkg_incamqp=1

and

> Set up AMQP authority, channel, and service properties by adding the
> contents of the add-dev.mqsc.tpl file to the bottom of the
> /incubating/mqadvanced-server-dev/10-dev.mqsc.tpl file in your cloned
> repository.